# PHP md5 + salt error executing

Tags: php, mysql

So when I try to execute my sql code I'm getting a error(error msg in bottom of post), the table works because a friend is working on the same database. I've gotten his sql query and that should work. So is it my executing function that's not working the the md5 function? It is working to get out data from the table if i not use the md5 function and I've got a connection.

admin.php (where i'm calling the function from)

```
<?php
    include('incl/header.php');
    include('class/CUser.php');
    if($_POST['login'])
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION['secureLogin']))
        {
            header('location: adminPage.php');
        }
        else
        {
            $user = new CUser();
            $res = $user->login($_SESSION['acronym'], $_SESSION['password']);
            if($res == true)
            {
                //$_SESSION['secureLogin']="true";
        //header('location: adminPage.php');

            }
            else
            {
                echo "false";
            }
        }
    }
    if(isset($_SESSION['secureLogin']))
    {
        header('location: adminPage.php');
    }
    else
    {
        echo "go back";
        //header('location: index.php');
    }
    include('incl/footer.php');
```

CUser.php(login function)

```
public function login($acronym, $password)
    {

        $res = $this->database->executeQuery("SELECT acronym, password FROM CDB_USER WHERE acronym = '$acronym' AND password = md5(concat('$password', salt)");

        print_r($res);
        if(empty($res))

        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

CDatabase.php (execute function)

```
public function executeQuery($sql)
     {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql); 
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     }
```

error msg:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1' in /storage/content/25/133425/..../public_html/kontaktApp/class/CDatabase.php:24 Stack trace: #0 /storage/content/25/133425/..../public_html/kontaktApp/class/CDatabase.php(24): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /storage/content/25/133425/..../public_html/kontaktApp/class/CUser.php(24): CDatabase->executeQuery('SELECT acronym,...') #2 /storage/content/25/133425/..../public_html/kontaktApp/admin.php(14): CUser->login('osf', '123') #3 {main} thrown in /storage/content/25/133425/..../public_html/kontaktApp/class/CDatabase.php on line 24

Comment: I assume your using MySql and not SqlServer? Not sure why you tagged both of them as they are not the same thing.

Comment: @SeanLange yeah sorry, mysql

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem but **your code is vulnerable to SQL injection!** You should always escape user inputs before passing a command to database.

Comment: Use a prepared statement instead, it's much less likely to introduce errors caused by including user data.

Comment: `md5(concat('$password', salt)` What is it `salt`? Where is the closing bracket?

Comment: You seem to be missing the closing parenthesis for your mysql md5() function?

Comment: Don't use MD5 for passwords, it is no longer considered secure. Use the `password_hash()` function instead.

Comment: Thank you guys, it was the ")"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I want to point out is that your code has a security flaw. Never, ever, interpolate a variable into a query in that way. You need to use Prepared Statements. Secondly, I don't find it to be a good idea to `md5()` the password in MySQL. This results in the actual password being sent to the MySQL server in cleartext, probably on a connection without TLS/SSL. Store the salt in your code, not in the DB, and then `md5()` the password in PHP. Try this:

admin.php

```
public function login($acronym, $password)
{
    $result = $this->database->executeQuery(
        "SELECT acronym, password FROM CDB_USER WHERE acronym = :acronym AND password = :password",
        array(':acronym' => $acronym, ':password' => md5($password . $salt))
    );

    print_r($result);

    return (bool) !empty($result);
}
```

CDatabase.php

```
public function executeQuery($sql, $bindValues = null)
{
    $statement = $this->conn->prepare($sql);

    if (is_array($bindValues))
    {
        foreach ($bindValues as $parameter => $value)
        {
            $statement->bindValue($parameter, $value);
        }
    }

    $statement->execute();

    return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

I also should point out that `md5()` is not a very secure hashing algorithm, and you should probably use `sha1()` or `hash('sha256', $password . $salt);` instead. Even `sha1()`, while much better than `md5()`, is still not as secure as `sha256`.

As for the original problem, it seems to be a parse error caused by a missing `)`. But, please take the security concerns mentioned here and by others in the comments seriously :)